# Make textblock appear on top of a button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mouseover, textblock

I'm struggling a bit with getting a textblock to appear on top on my customized button (with a picture) when mouseovering, is that possible? I want the name of the button to appear when you mouseover it.

Comment: Post code what have you tried and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the opacity of your `TextBlock` from 0 to 1 on mouse over using a trigger:

```
<TextBlock Text="XYZ">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

The same will not work using `Visibility` instead of `Opacity` because hit testing is disabled for an invisible or collapsed item and the mouse over is not detected.